# Delphi-search and retrieval value in text

Tags: html, delphi, parsing, html-parsing

Im downloading page to memo1.text and in this text i need to extract some value's to variables.
necessary part of downloaded code:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Nazwa1</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">    88.</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> 20%</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">86</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">108 h</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">     1.00000</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">8974296.0</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> 1.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Nazwa2</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">   282</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">---</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">261</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">1:26 h</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">     0.00212</td>
<td style="text-align: right;"> 312001.9</td>
<td style="text-align: center; color: #00cc00; "> 1.02</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Nazwa3</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">  2747</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">100%</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">1833</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">0:27 h</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">     0.02239</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">    364.4</td>
<td style="text-align: center; color: #00cc00; "> 1.19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Nazwa4</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">   413.6</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">100%</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">281</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">0:6 h</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">     0.00358</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">  32812.1</td>
<td style="text-align: center; color: #cc0000; "> 0.78</td>
</tr>
```

I must extract variable value "1.19" from "Nazwa3" table,
everything in table are variables, only name "nazwa3" is const.

```
uses
  regexpr;

function searchandextract(InputStr : string) : string;
var
  R : TRegExpr;
begin
  Result := '';
  R := TRegExpr.Create;
  try
    R.Expression := '<td style="text-align: left;">Nazwa3</td>(.+?)"> ([0-9\.]+)</td>(.+?)</tr>';
    if R.Exec(InputStr) then
    begin
      Result := R.Match[2];
    end;
  finally
    R.Free;
  end;
end;


  Label1.Caption := searchandextract(Memo1.Text);
```

But result of this function is empty and i dont have any idea why?

Comment: #1 most annoying kind of question on StackOverflow is the people who didn't know about Ansi versus Unicode, and #2 most annoying must be people who are parsing a giant mess of XML or HTML with regular expressions.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use regular expression to parse HTML files, rather take a look at an HTML parser library, in delphi you could use [DIHtmlParser](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/htmlparser/index) or [htmlp](http://htmlp.sourceforge.net/) .

Comment: @user2304765 That's not a fair question to ask. You could just try any one of the suggested html parsers and use one of the examples for that parser. It's time for you to do some legwork.

Comment: Finally i tried htmlp 

      procedure filtruj;
    var
      S: String;
      HtmlDoc: TDocument;
      Formatter: TBaseFormatter;
    begin
    S:=Form1.Memo1.Text;
      HtmlParser := THtmlParser.Create;
      try
        HtmlDoc := HtmlParser.parseString(S)
      finally
        HtmlParser.Free
      end;
    
      Formatter := TTextFormatter.Create;
      try
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Text := Formatter.getText(HtmlDoc);
      finally
        Formatter.Free
      end;
    
      HtmlDoc.Free;
    
      Form1.Memo1.SelStart := 0;
      Form1.Memo1.SelLength := 0;
    end;

Comment: First i parse this to text next i will use my code, but when im trying to use this with html file downloaded by Delphi i got error "Node is inserted somewhere it dosent belong" but when i save html file by Safari and open, it works

Comment: @user2304765, then you're probably passing to that parser malformed HTML document.

Comment: @TLama, sadly, HTML documents don't have to be well-formed, so parsers are required to endure malformed mark-up like <samp><kbd>foo</samp></kbd>